# Computing the transitive relations on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science

I have a project for my algebra seminar and I have no idea how can I make it. I would be very happy if someone would give me some tips.

Input: non-zero natural number n

• Output:

1. the number of transitive relations on a set A = {a_1, . . . , an}
2. the transitive relations on a set A = {a_1, . . . , an} (for n ≤ 4)

Example for n=2:

1. the number of transitive relations on a set A = {a_1, a_2} is 13
2. the transitive relations on a set A = {a_1, a_2} are:

R_1 = ∅,
R_2 = {(a_1, a_1)},
R_3 = {(a_1, a_2)},
R_4 = {(a_2, a_1)},

R_5 = {(a_2, a_2)},
R_6 = {(a_1, a_1),(a_1, a_2)},
R_7 = {(a_1, a_1),(a_2, a_1)},

R_8 = {(a_1, a_1),(a_2, a_2)},
R_9 = {(a_1, a_2),(a_2, a_2)},
R_10 = {(a_2, a_1),(a_2, a_2)},

R_11 = {(a_1, a_1),(a_2, a_2),(a_1, a_2)},
R_12 = {(a_1, a_1),(a_2, a_2),(a_2, a_1)},

R_13 = {(a_1, a_1),(a_1, a_2),(a_2, a_1),(a_2, a_2)}.

I know C++ and Python.

Comment: You might try the references given [here](http://oeis.org/A006905).  In any event, you can use the values to check your work, once you get the program working.

Comment: Look at equation $(12)$ in https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Pfeiffer/pfeiffer6.pdf

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for a program producing the output?